# How Can I add a dollar symbol in ASP.NET MVC5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

How do I add a dollar symbol in front of a TextBox, which cannot be edited? I want to have the dollar symbol so people don't need to type '$' by themselves. Here is my code:

```
    @Html.Label("lblP1", "Rate 1", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label", @style = "margin-right: 30px" })
<br />
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Pricing.Price1, null, new { htmlAttributes = new { @type = "string", @class = "form-control" } })
```

[image: Picture]

Answer (score 1):

This is an example using bootstrap:

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text">$</span>
  </div>   
  @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Pricing.Price1, null, new { htmlAttributes = new { @type = "string", @class = "form-control" } })      
</div>
```

Source: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/input-group/